# GEKKO optimal control with control variables

Tags: python, gekko

*Hi Everyone, I wrote the code below and normally the variable "y" should converge to "z_obj" but it's not the case. Here's the code and the plot I get*

[image]

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

m = GEKKO()

m.time = np.linspace(0,10,11)
z=np.repeat(20,11)
z_obj=m.Param(value=z)
y = m.Var(14)
u=m.CV(lb=0)
u.STATUS=1
u.FSTATUS=1
t = m.Param(value=m.time)
m.Equation(y.dt()==u)
m.Equation(u.dt()<=1)
m.Equation(u.dt()>=-5)
m.Obj((y-z_obj)**2)
m.options.IMODE=6
m.solve(disp=False)
plt.plot(m.time,y.value)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could someone  Please explain to me when to use ccontrolled and manipulated variables and the difference between them . Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a detailed explanation in the Gekko paper: https://www.mdpi.com/2227-9717/6/8/106/htm See Section 6.2.

Answer (score 1):

To enforce rate of change constraints on the Manipulated Variable use the `DMAXHI` and `DMAXLO` options of the `m.MV()` type.

[image: Rate of Change Limit on the MV]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

m = GEKKO()

m.time = np.linspace(0,10,11)
z=20
y = m.Var(14)
u=m.MV(lb=0)
u.STATUS=1; u.DMAXHI=1; u.DMAXLO=-5
t = m.Param(value=m.time)
m.Equation(y.dt()==u)
m.Obj((y-z)**2)
m.options.IMODE=6
m.solve(disp=False)
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,y.value,'r--',label='y')
plt.ylabel('y'); plt.legend()
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,u.value,'b-',label='u')
plt.ylabel('u'); plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.show()
```

Your current method is to create another `m.CV()` so that you have the derivatives available. This also works but creates additional equations for the `m.CV()`. There is additional information on `m.MV()` and `m.CV()` types in the [documentation](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/INFO), in the [Quick Start guide](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html), and [#17 of 18 in the Gekko examples](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/GekkoPythonOptimization).

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve it .. i must get rid of u.STATUS =1 and just Keep u.FSTATUS=1 . but i don't know why ! any explication please !